# Calculation of Vertex factor from Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry-breaking, interactions

I am studying spontaneous symmetry breaking of a complex scalar field $\phi(x)$ of a global $U(1)$ symmetry: $\phi(x)\to e^{i\alpha}\phi(x)$, where $\alpha$ is a real constant. I am considering the Lagrangian ($\mu^2<0$):
$$
\mathcal{L}=(\partial_{\mu}\phi)^{\ast}(\partial^{\mu}\phi)-\mu^2\phi^{\ast}\phi-\lambda(\phi^{\ast}\phi)^2,
$$
where the vacuum expectation value (vev) of the classical field $\phi$ is: $$\langle 0|\phi(x)|0\rangle=\frac{v}{\sqrt{2}}\neq0.$$
I have found the field value at the minimum of the potential $$V(\phi) = \mu^2\phi^{\ast}\phi+\lambda(\phi^{\ast}\phi)^2$$ to be $$\frac{v}{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{-\frac{\mu^2}{2\lambda}},$$ so that $\mu^2=-v^2\lambda$. To find the quantum correction to the field $\phi(x)$ near the minimum, I put $$\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[v+h(x)+i\xi(x)],$$ where the fields $h(x)$ and $\xi(x)$ are real. Then I expressed the Lagrangian in terms of these fields (barring any constant terms):
$$
\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}h)(\partial^{\mu}h)-\frac{1}{2}(2\lambda v^2)h^2-\lambda vh^3-\frac{\lambda}{4}h^4+\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\xi)(\partial^{\mu}\xi)-\frac{\lambda}{4}\xi^4-\frac{\lambda}{2}h(h+2v)\xi^2.
$$
(Now it is easy to see that the Goldstone modes $\xi$ are massless.)

**My question:** I can see that the interaction term in the Lagrangian is: $$\mathcal{L}_{\text{int}}=-\frac{\lambda}{2}h(h+2v)\xi^2.$$ How can I write the vertex factor? (Let's consider an elastic scattering process of the radial mode $h$ against the Goldstone mode $\xi$: $h(p_1)+\xi(p_2)\to h(p_3)+\xi(p_4)$.) Also, I am not sure whether one or two diagrams contribute at the tree level.